# Even powers and perfect squares

Tags: arithmetic

Does $2^{2k}$ (where $k$ is a natural number)  always result in perfect squares?If so, why?I just tried it with a few values and it appears to be true. I need the result for this to simplify a question.

Comment: Your question looks odd...or maybe I misunderstood: $$2^{2k}=\left(2^k\right)^2$$ and this is obviously a square...

Comment: Got it. It was simple enough. Thanks

Comment: @Integrator, i cannot accept an answer until a certain amount of time ( a couple of minutes) has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**
Use the fact that $a^{bc}=(a^b)^c=(a^c)^b$
$$2^{2k}=(2^{k})^2$$